# How to sequentially parse a single element of JSON file into vanilla python

Tags: python, json

I'm not certain where the problem is with this and I'm not really fluent with JSON, but here goes.

I have a dataset that I processed in pandas but won't likely be able to use later. I've exported it both as JSON records and JSON splits[1](https://datatofish.com/export-pandas-dataframe-json/).

```
[{'reference': '2019-73','Latitude': 1.045,
'Longitude': 103.65, date': '2019-09-30T00:00:00.000Z},
...{etc},{etc}]
```

To bring this back into a vanilla python file, I have this:

```
event_ids = set()
with codecs.open(data_directory, encoding='utf_8') as f:  # open the json file
    for event_json in f: # iterate through each line (json record) in the file
        event = json.loads(event_json)   # convert the json record to a Python dict
        event_ids.add(event(u'index') # add the event the the event_id set
```

But I get one of a few types of errors ("SyntaxError: unexpected EOF" while parsing as above, but others depending how I money things up.

My sense is this is because its trying to read the entire JSON as a single element but I don't know for sure though the error message goes away if I remove the last line of code. What am I doing wrong and equally importantly, what concept am I missing?

Comment: From the example in your question it's not clear that your input file actually consists of one-json-object-per-line. Your example seems to a show a single JSON object (a list) spanning multiple lines.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It's several thousand JSON records in total. But it looks like a list to me to. However, this is the way pandas.to_json did it. But I'll clarify the question too. I'd be agreeable to exporting in a different way with that would be better overall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hrokr, one thing you need to add is an iterator for each item:

```
event_latitudes=set()
data_directory='events.txt'
with codecs.open(data_directory, encoding='utf_8') as f:
     for event_json in f:
        event = json.loads(event_json)
        for item in event:         
           event_latitudes.add(item[u'Latitude'])
```

To deal with errors you can use try except blocks, especially around the for loop to deal with errors in the json. If you post a partial sample file that doesn't work on github, i can look at it and help further.

Answer (score 1):

Source json:

```
[
  {
    "data1": 0,
    "data2": 1,
    "data3": 2
  },
  {
    "data1": 0,
    "data2": 1,
    "data3": 2
  },
  {
    "data1": 0,
    "data2": 1,
    "data3": 2
  },
  {
    "data1": 0,
    "data2": 1,
    "data3": 2
  }
]
```

Python code:

```
import json

with open("file.json",'r') as f:
    var = json.load(f);
    print(var[0])
    print(var[1])
    print(var[2])
```

Result:

```
{'data1': 0, 'data2': 1, 'data3': 2}
{'data1': 0, 'data2': 1, 'data3': 2}
{'data1': 0, 'data2': 1, 'data3': 2}
```

You can read the entire file as a json using json.load , reading line per line is not recommended because json files may be formatted in multiple ways.